# How to gain the same behavior of divs like textboxes regarding padding

Tags: html, css

on setting a padding to an empty textbox it behaves like this:
[image]

doing the same with an empty div it behaves like this:
[image]

both elements have the same padding, but the textbox is higher than the div.

i suppose that this behavior is, because the textbox assumes that there will be a content (see cursor), but the div does not have a content and so it is not as high as the textbox without content.

how can i achieve that the div will have the same height as the textbox, even without content?

Comment: adding attribute `contenteditable="true"` and inserting some content e.g. `&nbsp;` in the div may help probably.

Answer (score 1):

Set a height on it. [Block level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) do not have a predefined height while some [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente) do, like an `<input>`.

```
div {
    height: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div
{
height: 20px;
}
```

There is no height, if you give some height, then it will be as text-box.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h16mghmb/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention height manually to `div` for `input` it will tag some default `height` once it renders

```css
input {
    padding:10px
}
div {
    border: 1px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 13px;
    background-color :#e9e9e9;
}
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/2pojs00q/)

Answer (score 0):

Since `div` is a container you will have to specify `height`.
`height:20px;` depending on the height of the text box.

Answer (score 0):

For a pure html/css solution:

```css
#div {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  Width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div" style="border: 1 px solid black"></div>
<br />
<input id="input" type="text" />
```

Comment: I was thinking it was necessary because he said he wanted the same height as the textbox, the only way to get the exact same height of the textbox in a div is using javascript/jQuery, if the height changes that is. It's a added extra of expandability/function  @hungerstar